# Class Input Structure without user's input

Tags: c++, class, structure

I need to get the info from this text **without** the user's input.

> Marble 2015 04 14 29 23 61 
> XANA 2007 05 17 56 47 11 
> Nefarius 2011 06 23 44 67 98 
> Toxi 2022 04 11 69 56 34

This is class `input` prototype: 
`void input(istream& ins);`

This what I put in its field:

```
void AQReport::input(istream& ins)
{
    int tday, tmonth, tyear, tozone, tcoarse, tfine;
    string tlocation;
    ifstream airQuality;
    
    ins >> tlocation >> tyear >> tmonth >> tday >> 
    tozone >> tcoarse >> tfine;
    
    setDate(tday, tmonth, tyear);
    setLocation(tlocation);
    setOzone(tozone);
    setCoarse(tcoarse);
    setFine(tfine);
}
```

And this is the `main` function:

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <fstream>;
#include <string>;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    AQReport account1, account2, account3, account4;
    ifstream airQuality;
    
    airQuality.open("airQuality.txt");
    if (airQuality.fail())
    {
        cout << "Can't open file. \n";
        exit (1);
    }
    
    account1.input(istream&);
    account2.input(istream&);
    account3.input(istream&);
    account4.input(istream&);
    
    account1.output(ostream&);
    account2.output(ostream&);
    account3.output(ostream&);
    account4.output(ostream&);
    
    airQuality.close();
    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to put `istream&` into the `input` parameter in the `main`, but I have multiple errors saying **" error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token"** for every `account`.

Comment: i think you want to pass the file object (`airQuality`) to the function, not the type `istream`.

Comment: You might want to take a few steps back, and refresh your beginjners book on how to pass arguments. `account1.input(istream&);` makes no sense.

Comment: Concerning `acount1.input(istream&);` and following: You intend to do a member function call but you provide a type (`istream&`) as if you would declare the function. This is what violates the compiler rules. It expects an expression (e.g. a variable, in your case `airQuality` / `std::cout`) instead of a type (`istream&` / `ostream&`). It recognizes the `&` (which could be an operator as well i.e. part of an expression) but the type before doesn't fit at all. This is what the error means.

Comment: Btw. you should get rid of the `using namespace std;`. This is often seen to buy a little bit convenience (e.g. to use `cout` instead of `std::cout`) but can cause you serious trouble. It pulls a lot of `std` symbols into the global namespace which you probably are not aware of. So, identifiers of the `std` library may collide with your own identifiers where you don't expect it -- resulting in even more confusing error messages.

Comment: My apologies, but I forgot to mention that I was instructed to use the `&` since he mentions _reference_.  Also, the `using namespace std;` is required as well. Again sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

If "istream" parameter from main from input function call was a viable variable then you should pass the parameter without the "&" from the end of the variable, in your case, and same for "ostream".

"void input(istream& ins);" - "istream" is the type of the parameter you should pass to the function and "&" means that the function will take the address of that parameter automatically without you needing to pass the address to the parameter, same for "void output(ofstream& );" function.

In my opinion, you should take it easy and start with some easier exercices.